# How to update NER training of existing transformer model code from v2 to SpaCy v3.x

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

I want to understand how to update the using example of NER updating the model to learn recognize new entity (here `ANIMAL`) from version 2.x of SpaCy v3.x:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/v2.3.x/examples/training/train_new_entity_type.py

```
LABEL = "ANIMAL"

# training data

TRAIN_DATA = [
    (
        "Horses are too tall and they pretend to care about your feelings",
        {"entities": [(0, 6, LABEL)]},
    ),
    ("Do they bite?", {"entities": []}),
    (
        "horses are too tall and they pretend to care about your feelings",
        {"entities": [(0, 6, LABEL)]},
    ),
    ("horses pretend to care about your feelings", {"entities": [(0, 6, LABEL)]}),
    (
        "they pretend to care about your feelings, those horses",
        {"entities": [(48, 54, LABEL)]},
    ),
    ("horses?", {"entities": [(0, 6, LABEL)]}),
]


@plac.annotations(
    model=("Model name. Defaults to blank 'en' model.", "option", "m", str),
    new_model_name=("New model name for model meta.", "option", "nm", str),
    output_dir=("Optional output directory", "option", "o", Path),
    n_iter=("Number of training iterations", "option", "n", int),
)
def main(model=None, new_model_name="animal", output_dir=None, n_iter=30):
    """Set up the pipeline and entity recognizer, and train the new entity."""
    random.seed(0)
    if model is not None:
        nlp = spacy.load(model)  # load existing spaCy model
        print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
    else:
        nlp = spacy.blank("en")  # create blank Language class
        print("Created blank 'en' model")
    # Add entity recognizer to model if it's not in the pipeline
    # nlp.create_pipe works for built-ins that are registered with spaCy
    if "ner" not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner")
        nlp.add_pipe(ner)
    # otherwise, get it, so we can add labels to it
    else:
        ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")

    ner.add_label(LABEL)  # add new entity label to entity recognizer
    # Adding extraneous labels shouldn't mess anything up
    ner.add_label("VEGETABLE")
    if model is None:
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    else:
        optimizer = nlp.resume_training()
    move_names = list(ner.move_names)
    # get names of other pipes to disable them during training
    pipe_exceptions = ["ner", "trf_wordpiecer", "trf_tok2vec"]
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe not in pipe_exceptions]
    # only train NER
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes), warnings.catch_warnings():
        # show warnings for misaligned entity spans once
        warnings.filterwarnings("once", category=UserWarning, module='spacy')

        sizes = compounding(1.0, 4.0, 1.001)
        # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
        for itn in range(n_iter):
            random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
            batches = minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=sizes)
            losses = {}
            for batch in batches:
                texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
                nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.35, losses=losses)
            print("Losses", losses)

    # test the trained model
    test_text = "Do you like horses?"
    doc = nlp(test_text)
    print("Entities in '%s'" % test_text)
    for ent in doc.ents:
        print(ent.label_, ent.text)

    # save model to output directory
    if output_dir is not None:
        output_dir = Path(output_dir)
        if not output_dir.exists():
            output_dir.mkdir()
        nlp.meta["name"] = new_model_name  # rename model
        nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
        print("Saved model to", output_dir)

        # test the saved model
        print("Loading from", output_dir)
        nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
        # Check the classes have loaded back consistently
        assert nlp2.get_pipe("ner").move_names == move_names
        doc2 = nlp2(test_text)
        for ent in doc2.ents:
        print(ent.label_, ent.text)
```

How this code should look like in SpaCy v3 so that it supports the `model=en_core_web_trf`?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [demo project for updating an NER component](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/pipelines/ner_demo_update) in the projects repo. In spaCy v3, instead of writing your own training loop, the recommended training process is to use a config file and the `spacy train` CLI command.

For updates like this in v3 there is no difference in how training is configured between transformer and non-transformer pipelines, since transformers no longer require extra components like in the example you posted.

Note that usually updating the pretrained NER component is not recommended, since it's easy to run into catastrophic forgetting. In the standard training process outlined in the docs, pretrained transformers are used as a feature source, so while the NER layer is from scratch, you aren't actually starting with nothing.

Comment: 1) I appreciate it is not recommended however how such training loop should look like in v3? 2) The example uses json in spacyv2 format can you advise how to use the spacyv3 binary format in that case?